# How can I improve this Test Class for a VF page Custom Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am learning to create Test Classes and realize this example needs improvement and that is why I am posting it here.

My Controller Extension is on a VF Page within a Customer Community with a standardController="Case" and the VF page will be loaded with a param of ?Id=

Here is the Controller Extension

```
public class CaseArticlesExtension {   
    public Id RecordId { get; set; }

    public CaseArticlesExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    RecordId = stdController.getId();
    }   

public KnowledgeArticleVersion[] getArticles() {

    CaseArticle[] caseArticles = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE CaseId = :RecordId];

    list<Id> kaIds = new List<Id>();

    for (CaseArticle art: caseArticles) {
        kaIds.add(art.KnowledgeArticleId);
    }

    KnowledgeArticleVersion[] Articles = [SELECT UrlName, Title, Summary, ArticleType 
        FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
        WHERE PublishStatus= 'Online' 
        AND Language = 'en_US'
        AND KnowledgeArticleId IN :kaIds];

    return Articles;
}
}
```

Here is my Test Class

```
@isTest
public class CaseArticlesExtensionTest {

    static testMethod void runPositiveTestCases() {    

        //Set up user
        User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias='alias'];

        //Run As U1
        System.RunAs(u1){ 

        System.debug('something something');

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;

        User_Guides__kav k = new User_Guides__kav();
        k.Title = 'APEX TEST';
        k.UrlName = 'APEX-TEST';
        k.Language = 'en_US';
        insert k;
        k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM User_Guides__kav WHERE Id = :k.Id];    
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(k.KnowledgeArticleId, true);

        Case c = new Case();
        //c.RecordType = Default;
        c.Origin = 'Web';
        c.Status = 'Working';
        c.AccountId = a.Id;
        insert c;

        CaseArticle ca = new CaseArticle();
        ca.CaseId = c.Id;
        ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.KnowledgeArticleId;
        insert ca;            

        PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseDetail;
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',c.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        Test.startTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        CaseArticlesExtension ext = new CaseArticlesExtension(controller);            

        ext.getArticles();

            System.assertEquals(c.Id, ext.RecordId, 'Case Id No Good');

        KnowledgeArticleVersion[] ArticlesB = [SELECT UrlName, Title, Summary, ArticleType 
        FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
        WHERE PublishStatus= 'Online' 
        AND Language = 'en_US'
        AND KnowledgeArticleId = :k.KnowledgeArticleId];

            System.assertEquals('APEX TEST', ArticlesB[0].Title, 'Title No Good');

        CaseArticle[] caseArticlesB = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE CaseId = :ext.RecordId];



    System.assertEquals(ca.KnowledgeArticleId, caseArticlesB[0].KnowledgeArticleId, 'Knowledge Id No Good');

    Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

}

This Test Class gets 100% coverage.

What do I need to make this a better Test Class?

**Update:** I updated the Test Class for some errors I found when trying to publish the Article and attach it to a case.  Now I need to do some assertions as was recommended in the comments

**Update 2** I have added some Assertions. Are these Assertions testing the right results to be useful?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, be aware that your tests are not actually testing anything. All they are doing is executing lines of code. You are not testing for appropriate outcomes after the code is executed. This leave your code vulnerable to failure while your "test" continue to pass. Proper test methods will query for and assert data after tests have ran. Also, your test.starttest() and test.stopTest() should be around the code you are testing so the last 3 lines. This gives you a new set of governor limits amount other things

Comment: Excellent Point @Eric I will make sure to add some assertions and move the starttest

Comment: you should mock the user, not query for one

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with this line: `kaIds.add(art.KnowledgeArticleId);` is that no results are returned from your query, so nothing gets added to the `kaIds` list. It might be a typo but I don't see an `insert` statement after you instantiate your `CaseArticle` in the test class (which could explain why no results are returned).

Also, as noted in the documentation, `Create all test data before calling the Test.startTest method.`. It shouldn't be a cause of any issue but since you're learning, it's best to implement your code according to the suggested best practices.

One last note:

```
    PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseDetail;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',c.Id);
```

I'm not sure if this will cause an issue in a test environment, but I would normally set the parameter prior to calling `Test.setCurrentPage()`

e.g.

```
    PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseDetail;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id', c.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

Comment: no typo, I did not have that in there.  Now that I put that in there my test class is failing. I need to look at that section I must be attaching articles to the case incorrectly.

Comment: @Jason Well, that's something.. I edited my answer and added something to it.

Comment: OK this question is sort of broken due to the issue I have discovered when trying to insert ca   I will have to create a new question regarding how to attach an article to a case in the test class since I am not figuring out my mistake there

Comment: Here is the new question that came up from Antonio's comment regarding my not inserting ca  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118794/how-do-i-attach-an-article-to-a-case-in-a-test-class