# How do I attach an Article to a Case in a Test Class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am trying to figure out how to fix the part of my test class that is attaching an Article to a Case.

section of code from my test class:

```
CaseArticle ca = new CaseArticle();
ca.CaseId = c.Id;
ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.Id;
insert ca;
```

Error I get is:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Article ID: id value of incorrect type: ka3c0000000Chu5AAC: [KnowledgeArticleId]
```

I also tried :

```
CaseArticle ca = new CaseArticle();
ca.CaseId = c.Id;
ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.KnowledgeArticleId;
insert ca;
```

Error I got is:

```
System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid ID.
```

My Controller Extension is on a VF Page within a Customer Community with a standardController="Case" and the VF page will be loaded with a param of ?Id=

Here is the Controller Extension

```
public class CaseArticlesExtension {   
    public Id RecordId { get; set; }

    public CaseArticlesExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    RecordId = stdController.getId();
    }   

public KnowledgeArticleVersion[] getArticles() {

    CaseArticle[] caseArticles = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE CaseId = :RecordId];

    list<Id> kaIds = new List<Id>();

    for (CaseArticle art: caseArticles) {
        kaIds.add(art.KnowledgeArticleId);
    }

    KnowledgeArticleVersion[] Articles = [SELECT UrlName, Title, Summary, ArticleType 
        FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
        WHERE PublishStatus= 'Online' 
        AND Language = 'en_US'
        AND KnowledgeArticleId IN :kaIds];

    return Articles;
}
}
```

This is my Test Class

```
@isTest
public class CaseArticlesExtensionTest {

    static testMethod void runPositiveTestCases() {    

        //Set up user
        User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias='alias'];

        //Run As U1
        System.RunAs(u1){ 

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;

        User_Guides__kav k = new User_Guides__kav();
        k.Title = 'APEX TEST';
        k.UrlName = 'APEX-TEST';
        k.Language = 'en_US';
        insert k;     
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(k.Id, true);

        Case c = new Case();
        //c.RecordType = Default;
        c.Origin = 'Web';
        c.Status = 'Working';
        c.AccountId = a.Id;
        insert c;

        CaseArticle ca = new CaseArticle();
        ca.CaseId = c.Id;
        ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.Id;
        insert ca;            

        PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseDetail;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',c.Id);

        Test.startTest();            

        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        CaseArticlesExtension ext = new CaseArticlesExtension(controller);            

        ext.getArticles();

        Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I may have located the solution.

Adding this line before trying to publish the article seemed to fix my Id issue

k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM User_Guides__kav WHERE Id = :k.Id];

After doing that then using the following line in my CaseArticle section seems to be working.  I still need to add some Assertions to verify.

ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.KnowledgeArticleId;

If I change the test class to the following it appears to solve the problem.

```
@isTest
public class CaseArticlesExtensionTest {

    static testMethod void runPositiveTestCases() {    
        Test.startTest();

        //Set up user
        User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias='aconn'];

        //Run As U1
        System.RunAs(u1){ 

        System.debug('something something');

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;

        User_Guides__kav k = new User_Guides__kav();
        k.Title = 'APEX TEST';
        k.UrlName = 'APEX-TEST';
        k.Language = 'en_US';
        insert k;
        k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM User_Guides__kav WHERE Id = :k.Id];    
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(k.KnowledgeArticleId, true);

        Case c = new Case();
        //c.RecordType = Default;
        c.Origin = 'Web';
        c.Status = 'Working';
        c.AccountId = a.Id;
        insert c;

        CaseArticle ca = new CaseArticle();
        ca.CaseId = c.Id;
        ca.KnowledgeArticleId = k.KnowledgeArticleId;
        insert ca;            

        PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseDetail;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',c.Id);

        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        CaseArticlesExtension ext = new CaseArticlesExtension(controller);            

        ext.getArticles();

        Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```